# How to evaluate reader conditionals from a Clojure REPL

Tags: vim, clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

I understand how to write code using [reader conditionals](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Reader+Conditionals). But I'm not able to evaluate code with reader conditionals in the REPL, which makes it rather difficult to use [Vim Fireplace](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace) to evaluate code in my `.cljc` files. (I imagine Emacs and Cursive users would have similar problems, but perhaps their different approaches give them ways around this.)

The error I get when I try to evaluate a `.cljc` with reader conditionals using Fireplace is

```
RuntimeException Conditional read not allowed  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
```

I was able to find [this article](http://danielcompton.net/2015/05/21/conditional-read-not-allowed-clojure-reader-conditionals) which points out that if you try to use reader conditionals from a file with a `.clj` extension, you'll get this error. That suggests to me that the lein REPL is attempting to evaluate the code as though it's coming from a `.clj` file.

Is there a way to get the lein repl to interpret things differently to avoid this problem? Some other way around this? Or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated `tools.repl` from version `0.2.3` to `0.2.11`, and that seems to have done the trick! Not sure what the minimal version is that would solve this, but I can't imagine there's much point in not just upgrading to the latest.

(I should also note that I upgraded lein from `2.5.1` to `2.6.1`, but that didn't solve the issue in isoloation; Doubt it's necessary, but worth trying if the above doesn't resolve things for you...)